# Powerbuilder ORCA API Deploy

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy

I am trying to deploy my powerbuilder project to EAServer with orca api. But I am gettiing error **-21 PBORCA_CBBUILDERROR (Deployment failed with errors)**. Also, callback function(BuildErrProc) is not being called. How can I overcome this problem? BTW I am using WindowsXP-32bit, Powerbuilder 11.2, EAServer 5.5, QT-4.8.0 opensource vs2010.

```c
void __stdcall BuildErrProc(LPVOID lpUserData) {
  PPBORCA_BLDERR blderr = (PPBORCA_BLDERR)lpUserData;
  QString s;
  s = QString::fromStdWString(blderr->lpszMessageText);
  QMessageBox::information(0,"",s);
}

int WINAPI BuildProject(QString currentApplLibName,QString currentApplName,QString projectLibName,QString projectName,QStringList libraryNames)
{
  PBORCA_BLDPROC fpBuildErrProc;
  PPBORCA_BLDERR pBldErrData;
  fpBuildErrProc = (PBORCA_BLDPROC) BuildErrProc;
  pBldErrData = (PPBORCA_BLDERR) new PBORCA_BLDERR;
  memset(pBldErrData, 0x00, sizeof(PBORCA_BLDERR));

  HPBORCA hORCASession;
  hORCASession = SessionOpen();
  printf("Setting library list..\n");    
  LPTSTR* pLibNames = new LPTSTR[libraryNames.size()];
  for(int i=0;i<libraryNames.size();i++) {
      pLibNames[i]=(LPTSTR)libraryNames.at(i).utf16();
  }
  int r = PBORCA_SessionSetLibraryList(hORCASession, pLibNames, libraryNames.size());
  if(r==0) {
      printf("Library list OK.\n");
      QMessageBox::information(0,"",currentApplName);
      r = PBORCA_SessionSetCurrentAppl(hORCASession,(LPTSTR)currentApplLibName.utf16(),(LPTSTR)currentApplName.utf16());
      if(r==0) {
          printf("Setting current appl OK.\n");         
          r = PBORCA_BuildProject(hORCASession,(LPTSTR)projectLibName.utf16(),(LPTSTR)projectName.utf16(),fpBuildErrProc,pBldErrData);
          if (r==0) {
              printf("Building current prj OK.\n");
          } else {
              printf("Build FAILURE:%d\n",r);
          }
      } else {
          printf("Current appl FAILURE.\n");
      }
  } else {
      printf("Library list FAILURE:%d\n",r);
  }
  SessionClose(hORCASession);
  return r;
}
```

Comment: I resolved it. Library list was wrong. When I set correct lib list it built the project successfully.

Comment: You might want to put that as an answer below so that your question shows up as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it. Library list was wrong. When I set correct lib list it built the project successfully.